# Docker for traditional web application with load balancing?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker, haproxy

This is rather a concept question than a technical question.

My question is: if I am going to

- Setup a wordpress eshop (woocommerce) , using Apache
- using Docker,
- with load balancing, using HAProxy
- implement the Micro Service Architecture

How should I implement it?

Here is what I came up with:

- 1 Container: Apache + PHP
- 1 Container: MySQL

But I don't know how to integrate HAProxy into the architecure.

Can anyone please give me an idea of it?

Also how to do load-balancing if all containers are in a single machine?

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: If you only plan to have one instance of Apache, what are you going to load-balance over?  More typical would be to have one database and multiple Apaches.  And there's generally little point load-balancing over multiple Apaches on the same machine; the value comes from having multiple machines.  I suggest you read some articles like http://blog.hypriot.com/post/docker-compose-nodejs-haproxy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar thing and that too over multiple machines.

Firstly, unless you have multiple instances of Apache+PHP, haproxy doesnt come into the picture at all.

Otherwise: An ideal setup would be:

request from user-->haproxy-->multiple (Apache + PHP) -->MySQL.

Here Haproxy would give you a common public IP(of the host machine) and port for your app to be accessed. Whenever anyone accesses this IP and port, request would be forwarded to one of your Apache+PHP containers. You will have to edit your haproxy.cfg file and list the IP and port of the containers.

This link might help you:
https://serversforhackers.com/load-balancing-with-haproxy

Please note that here Haproxy is running on your machine and not as a Docker container.

Comment: Thank you.  So one more question: how about your php files?  Is it loaded using Docker VOLUMN syntax as a single directory where containers can access?

Comment: You mean the source code for your web application? Well, a good practice would be to copy them inside your container rather than volume mounting. Volume mounting should be used where the data needs to be  persisted. This can be the case with the mysql container of yours. This is because if the mysql container goes down, you wouldnt want to loose the data. However, this is not the case with the PHP files.

Comment: Thank you.  The reason I ask it is that it is quite normal for developers to do certain maintenance like "updating a string" or "updating a file", "add an image" and so on.  If we pack the source code into a container, then I guess developers need to update file(s) to each container one by one.  That's why I would like to ask this.  Did you manage to have similar experience?

Comment: Yer, right. You should do a volume mounting in this case. But once the code is stable and complete, copy it into the image rather than mounting. What my experience says is that, volume mounting should only be used for dynamic data (like yours) and for persisting data (databases).